# How to install Windows X on Raspberry Pi 2?

Tags: windows, pi-2

Windows Developer Program for IoT has announced that they will support, and supply a FREE version of Windows X on the Raspberry PI 2.

Has anybody had any beta versions running on the Pi 2 and is it possible how can I install it on to he Pi2?

Comment: Does it require Windows IoT?  If so you'll have to wait for the release of Windows IoT.

Comment: I don't know... :)

Comment: That makes two of us.

Comment: http://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/02/02/windows_10_raspberry_pi_2_eben_upton_interview/ implies they porting Windows to it because RT already runs on armv7 ... so if its got a Desktop )or even not( and I can run .NET (Micro or .NET5) on it... I want *drool*

Comment: This question is not about what is the Windows 10 on Pi but how to install it. The answers on the other question does not answer how I can install Windows 10 on to the Pi.

Comment: You can't.  Windows IoT for the Pi has not been released.  You have to sign up to the developers program (in blood).  Nobody knows what Windows IoT for the Pi will contain.  It may just be a command line interface.

Comment: Yup and once its released the answer will be here, nicely indexed. Already signed up and waiting.... with a Pi2...